# How to transpose column headers to be rows without moving rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

Not sure if I have worded the question right. I am using sql server  2014 management studio.

I have this table:

```
|------------------|--01/12/2016--|--02/12/2016--|--03/12/2016--|--04/12/2016--|<br>
 |----Place------|--Count--Value|   Count   --Value|    Count--     Value|--    Count--value<br> 
|--London------|    random data--|random data--|-------------------|--------------------|                       
|--Manchester|-------------------|------------------|random data---|---------------------|                          
|--Birmingham|--------------------|---etc------------|etc----------------|-etc------------------|                           
|--Leeds--------|                           
|--Luton---------|                          
|--Scotland-----|
```

What I want to do is transpose the dates from the column headers to rows so it looks like this:

```
Place   ----------|---dates------|  Count--------|  Value<br>
London  --------|01/12/2016     
Manchester  --|01/12/2016       
Birmingham  --|01/12/2016       
Leeds   ---------|01/12/2016        
Luton   ----------|01/12/2016       
Scotland    ------|01/12/2016       
London--------  |02/12/2016     
Manchester--    |02/12/2016     
Birmingham--    |02/12/2016     
Leeds   ---------|02/12/2016        
Luton   ----------|02/12/2016       
Scotland------  |02/12/2016     
London  --------|03/12/2016     
Manchester  --|03/12/2016       
Birmingham  --|03/12/2016       
Leeds   ----------|03/12/2016       
Luton   -----------|03/12/2016      
Scotland    -------|03/12/2016      
London  ---------|04/12/2016        
Manchester  ---|04/12/2016      
Birmingham  ---|04/12/2016      
Leeds   ----------|04/12/2016       
Luton-----------    |04/12/2016     
Scotland    -------|04/12/2016
```

I have searched for transposing data but none seem to cover this situation.

Comment: mySql <> sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *unpivot* the data.  I think `cross apply` is the easiest way:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (city, cast('2016-01-12' as date), [01/12/2016]),
             (city, cast('2016-02-12' as date), [02/12/2016]),
             (city, cast('2016-03-12' as date), [03/12/2016]),
             . . .
     ) v(city, dte, cnt);
```

Note that this makes the second column a *bona fide* date.

Comment: but is there a way to do this much more efficiently? as it not just those dates bu in fact 1000's of columns named as dates.

Comment: @VS1SQL . . . SQL Server has a limit of 1,024 columns for a normal table.  "Thousands" does seem right.  In any case, you should fix the data so it is generated in a better format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by the library called "reshape" in R

The simple code :

```
reshape::melt(DF,id="Place")
```

If you have any other dependent column like place, you can follow this code.

```
reshape::melt(DF,id=c("Place","Type"))
```

The reference link is: https://www.r-statistics.com/tag/transpose/